# Java 8: How to create DateTimeFormatter with milli, micro or nano seconds?

Tags: java, parsing, time, java-time

I need to create the formatter for parsing timestamps with optional milli, micro or nano fractions of second.

For example, for my needs I see the following opportunity:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                   .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
                                   .appendLiteral('-')
                                   .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                                   .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
                                   .toFormatter();
```

Or it is also possible to use `appendFraction(field, minWidth, maxWidth, decimalPoint)`.

However in these cases will it be possible to parse timestamps with any number of decimals (up to 9 or maxWidth). How to achieve that we can parse (optionally) only 3, 6 or 9 numbers after the comma?

It should be possible to parse the following time parts:

- `HH:mm:ss.SSS`
- `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`
- `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS`

But impossible to parse: `HH:mm:ss.SSSS`.

Comment: Don't think you can, but why do you care? What would be wrong with accepting e.g. 4 fraction digits? It is perfectly valid according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 15):

You can use the optional sections pattern (delimited by `[]`), and create 3 optional sections: 1 for 9 digits, another for 6 digits and another one for 3 digits.

According to [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-), you can use the `S` pattern (which is equivalent to [NANO_OF_SECOND field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#NANO_OF_SECOND)):

```
Pattern  Count  Equivalent builder methods
-------  -----  --------------------------
S..S     1..n   appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, n, n, false)
```

*In the old API (`SimpleDateFormat`), [`S` is the pattern used for milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but in the new API it was changed to nanoseconds.*

So the formatter will be created like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // here is the same as your code
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).appendLiteral('-')
    // time (hour/minute/seconds)
    .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss")
    // optional nanos, with 9, 6 or 3 digits
    .appendPattern("[.SSSSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSS]")
    // offset
    .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

Some tests:

```
// 3 digits
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123Z", formatter)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z

// 6 digits
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123456Z", formatter)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123456Z

// 9 digits
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123456789Z", formatter)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123456789Z

// 4 digits (throws DateTimeParseException: Text '20161201-10:30:45.1234Z' could not be parsed at index 21)
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.1234Z", formatter));
```

The output is:

> 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z
>   2016-12-01T10:30:45.123456Z
>   2016-12-01T10:30:45.123456789Z
>   Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20161201-10:30:45.1234Z' could not be parsed at index 21

---

**Notes:**

- This instance of `DateTimeFormatter` is **not** good for **formatting**, because it prints all optional sections (so the nanosecond will be printed 3 times):

  ```
  // don't use it to format, it prints all optional sections
  // (so nanos are printed 3 times: with 9, 6 and 3 digits)
  OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123Z", formatter);
  System.out.println(formatter.format(odt));
  // output is 20161201Z-10:30:45.123000000.123000.123Z
  ```

So if you want to display your dates in another format, consider creating another `DateTimeFormatter`.

- In your code you used `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`. According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME), in this formatter the seconds are optional. If you want to have the same behaviour, just change the time pattern to:

  ```
  // time (hour/minute) with optional seconds
  .appendPattern("HH:mm[:ss]")
  ```
- The `[]` pattern is a nice shortcut to make optional sections, but you could also create them using `optionalStart()` with `appendFraction()`:

  ```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      // here is the same as your code
      .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).appendLiteral('-')
      // time (hour/minute/seconds)
      .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss")
      // optional nanos with 9 digits (including decimal point)
      .optionalStart()
      .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 9, 9, true)
      .optionalEnd()
      // optional nanos with 6 digits (including decimal point)
      .optionalStart()
      .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 6, 6, true)
      .optionalEnd()
      // optional nanos with 3 digits (including decimal point)
      .optionalStart()
      .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, true)
      .optionalEnd()
      // offset
      .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
      // create formatter
      .toFormatter();
  ```

This formatter works exactly the same way as the first one created with `[]` pattern.

---

## Side effect

As @SeanVanGorder noticed [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373144/java-8-how-to-create-datetimeformatter-with-milli-micro-or-nano-seconds/44390354#comment75790244_44390354), this formatter has the side effect of accepting multiple patterns for the nanosecond field, but it works only if the values are the same:

```
// side effect
// multiple nanos values (accepts multiple values if they're all the same)
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123000.123Z", formatter)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123000000.123Z", formatter)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123000000.123000.123Z", formatter)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z
```

All the lines above output `2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z`, but notice that they accept all the optional values (like `.123000000.123`). As the values are the same, the parsing is done without errors.

If the values are different, though, it throws an exception:

```
// multiple nanos values (throws exception if values are different)
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20161201-10:30:45.123000.124Z", formatter)); // exception
```

If this behaviour is not desired, the only alternative is to create lots of different formatters (one for each case) and do a `for` loop until you get a valid parsed value (very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44376693/7605325)).

First I created a method receives a list of `DateTimeFormatter`'s and a `TemporalQuery` to convert the parsed string to any object you want:

```
// method to parse, it receives a list of DateTimeFormatter and a TemporalQuery to convert the parsed string
public <T> T parse(String input, TemporalQuery<T> query, DateTimeFormatter... formatters) {
    for (DateTimeFormatter fmt : formatters) {
        try {
            // try to parse
            return fmt.parse(input, query);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    // none worked, throw exception
    throw new DateTimeParseException("Text '" + input + "' could not be parsed", input, 0);
}
```

Now you just need to create the formatters and use them in the `parse` method:

```
// alternative: have 3 different formatters
DateTimeFormatter f1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // here is the same as your code
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).appendLiteral('-')
    // time (hour/minute/seconds/3 digit nanos)
    .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    // offset
    .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
DateTimeFormatter f2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // here is the same as your code
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).appendLiteral('-')
    // time (hour/minute/seconds/6 digit nanos)
    .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
    // offset
    .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
DateTimeFormatter f3 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // here is the same as your code
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).appendLiteral('-')
    // time (hour/minute/seconds/9 digit nanos)
    .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS")
    // offset
    .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();

// all formatters
DateTimeFormatter[] formatters = new DateTimeFormatter[] { f1, f2, f3 };

// 3 digits
System.out.println(parse("20161201-10:30:45.123Z", OffsetDateTime::from, formatters)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123Z
// 6 digits
System.out.println(parse("20161201-10:30:45.123456Z", OffsetDateTime::from, formatters)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123456Z
// 9 digits
System.out.println(parse("20161201-10:30:45.123456789Z", OffsetDateTime::from, formatters)); // 2016-12-01T10:30:45.123456789Z

// 4 digits (throws exception)
System.out.println(parse("20161201-10:30:45.1234Z", OffsetDateTime::from, formatters));
// java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20161201-10:30:45.1234Z' could not be parsed

// multiple values (throws exception)
System.out.println(parse("20161201-10:30:45.123000.123Z", OffsetDateTime::from, formatters));
// java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20161201-10:30:45.123000.123Z' could not be parsed
```

Note that I used the method reference `OffsetDateTime::from` as a `TemporalQuery`, but you can change it to any query you need.

Comment: I was thinking this would allow multiple decimals (like `.123456.123`), but upon testing it looks like DateTimeFormatter doesn't accept multiple different values for the same field. It does accept `.123000.123`, though, but I doubt that's an issue.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder Indeed, that's a side effect of having lots of optional sections for the same field. But as you said, it accepts only if the value is the same (like in your example, or `.123000000.123000.123`, or `.123000000.123`). If input is like `.123000.456`, it throws an exception. I think this can be avoided by validating the input - or maybe you don't need to, if you make sure the input strings are generated correctly (OP didn't detailed how the inputs are generated, but I assume they come from date/time objects). Anyway, I agree that's a minor issue. Thanks!

Comment: With multiple alternatives for number of digits, make sure to put them in the pattern string **in order of decreasing length**. Otherwise, parsing seems to fail (but I'm not sure why).

Answer (score 3):

`DateTimeFormatter` only supports width ranges, so this wouldn't be possible with a single instance. You could make 3 separate formatters using `.appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, #, #, true)` where # is 3, 6, or 9. Then try them in sequence, ignoring any `DateTimeParseException` until the last one:

```
private static TemporalAccessor parse(String text) {
    try {
        return formatter3.parse(text);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    try {
        return formatter6.parse(text);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return formatter9.parse(text); // let this one throw
}
```

Another option would be checking the input with a regular expression first, something like `text.matches("[^.]+(.+\\.(\\d{3}|\\d{6}|\\d{9})\\b.*)?")`.