# how to convert a java timestamp to a string respecting the timezone with nanosecond resolution

Tags: java, timestamp, timezone, tostring

I want to convert a timestamp to a string given a timezone argument (in Java).  From the code I'm looking at internally the timestamp has nanosecond precision (or at least one can convert it to nanoseconds and I don't care since the output format I want to generate isn't that precise).

The DateFormat allows an S specifier and will apply a TimeZone, but it seems to do only 3 digits (milliseconds?) precision. Using toString gives 6 digits of precision within the seconds (microseconds?) but doesn't seem to take a TimeZone argument.

I need something that does both, allows a TimeZone specifier and gives 6 digits of precision within a second.

What to use?

Comment: Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373144/java-8-how-to-create-datetimeformatter-with-milli-micro-or-nano-seconds), maybe it contains helpful information concerning your requirements.

Comment: Yes, that explains the use of S (i.e. SSSSS rather than just S) that I seem to need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean a `java.sql.Timestamp` that you are getting from an SQL database where it was a timestamp either with or without time zone.

### Use java.time

First, you don’t need that. The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead prefer to get from your database:

- If your database column is a `timestamp with time zone`, which it should be, then get an `OffsetDateTime` (with some JDBC drivers an `Instant` works too).
- If your database column is `timestamp` without time zone (not recommended), then get a `LocalDateTime`. The problem with this is that a `LocalDateTime` is a date and time without time zone, so not a unique point in time, so unsuited for a timestamp.

The mentioned types are all from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and they all have nanosecond precision.

Example:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = yourResultSet.getObject("my_timestamp_col", OffsetDateTime.class);
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Example output:

> 2018-11-29T22:34:56.123456789Z

The trailing `Z` in the output means Zulu time zone, UTC or offset zero.

You wanted to apply a given time zone. So for example:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Guyana"));
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

> 2018-11-29T18:34:56.123456789-04:00[America/Guyana]

Getting a type from java.time from the result set using `ResultSet.getObject` requires JDBC 4.2 (or a modern JPA implementation or what you use for data access). Most of us have that.

### Handling a Timestamp from a legacy API

In case you either haven’t got JDBC 4.2 yet or you are getting the `Timestamp` from a legacy API that you can’t afford to change just now:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = yourTimestamp.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Guyana"));
```

If you have specific requirements for your string output, use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format your `ZonedDateTime`. This is described in many places, just search.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.